# Firestore queries wherequalto vs wherestartat and endat? performance and pricing?

Tags: android, firebase, performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore database for my Android application, here in some places I have to perform queries based on some part of the String for example:
if a document contains a field `txnId` which contains value as "abcd-efg-jkl" so I want to query this document using whereStartAt("abcd").whereEndAt("abce") ( want fetch all those documents which starts with 'abcd')
Now my question is what is the performance when I use exact search as equalTo operator versus startAt? and how pricing will be affected?

Answer (score 1):

> I use exact search as equalTo operator versus startAt?

It doesn't really matter which one you use, both are equally performant, so you should use the one that returns the desired results. Please note that in Firestore, the query performance depends on the number of items you request and **not** on the number of items you search. For instance, the time for retrieving, let's say 5 elements, from a query that contains an `equalTo()` call will always be the same as the time for retrieving 5 elements from a query that contains a `startAt()` call.

> and how pricing will be affected?

The price will not be affected by the methods that you are using. The price will be affected by the number of elements that are returned by your queries. Every element that is returned by a query costs exactly one document read. However, every query costs at least one read to execute, even if the [query yields no results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations).